# Using position_dodge preserve=single together with facet_wrap free_x

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am creating a boxplot as follows

```
result = ggplot(
data = data,
aes(
  x = reorder(c, c_num),
  y = total,
  fill =paste(m, co),
  group = c
)
) +
geom_boxplot(lwd=0.8, position=position_dodge2(width=0.5, preserve="single")) +
scale_x_discrete() +
facet_wrap(m ~ co, nrow = 1, scale = "free_x") +
```

but it seems like the

```
preserve="single"
```

has no effect when the number of conditions in the facetted group is 1.

[image]

Is there a way to prevent this?

I really want the free scale in the x axis, but I don't want the boxes to have different sizes, and I don't want to include fake data that would artificially create groups of the same size, if possible (I think that would widen too much the plot in some cases).

Comment: you could try using `facet_grid` and `space = "free"`?

Comment: Thanks, that's getting closer. Now I need to adjust the width so that my facet label can still be readable.